# Folder synchronization software for great volumes and with a tracking database

Tags: backup, sync, dropbox, sparkleshare, wuala

I'm looking for a synchronization software for my iMac-MacBook configuration. Other systems would be a plus.
I'd like to synchronize everything, which is many Gb, also for a backup purpose.
I know there already are many questions about this, but none of them replies to a real scenario of actually working with two computers.

The ideal solution would be some service like Dropbox with no space limitation and using either a local server or p2p.

I tried rsync-like software (like Unison, Synkron, Chronosync, ViceVersa...), but they all don't recognize user actions like delete or rename, bringing deleted files back.
I tried Dropbox, Wuala and such, but they are too limited in size, and they use the web: I'd like to synchronize all my folders, including music and movies.
I tried git or svn solutions (Sparkleshare and some more), but they use too much disk space. When you delete a huge file it stays in history, and even without that, the repository size almost doubles.
I tried solutions that create some sort of virtual drive, like LiveDrive, but it is unsuitable for many applications when you need your files in their place.

I'm willing to pay for this service, but I couldn't find anything, not even for a business customers. Is everyone living with this or am I missing something?

Comment: Dropbox currently has a storage quota of 2TB+ with 2GB max file size. Box.net has no storage quota but also 2GB max file size. I'm pretty sure there are other similar services that also have unlimited storage quotas as long as you're willing to pay for it. And if you want file versioning, then you need to accept that versioning requires additional storage space (all the extra versions of each file, including deleted files, has to be stored somewhere).

Comment: Dropbox for 1Tb (not 2) costs almost 800$ and is for teams, box.net has the minimum of 3 users, and it costs 540$. While I understand that online storage might cost a lot, there is no need for a synchronization tool to use any.

Comment: So is your complaint that they don't offer enough space or that they cost too much? Also, there's no need for a synchronization tool to use any what?

Comment: My complaint is that, as I tried to say in my question, they use network storage, while it is not necessary to use any online storage when you want to synchronize your home computer with your laptop. And, while doing that, they charge you for something you don't want nor need.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to not use any online storage. But the problem with that is you'd either need to set up one computer as the central repository or keep a versioning repo on each computer. In the first case, you wouldn't be able to sync files when that computer is offline, and in the latter case, you'd use twice as much storage for 2 computers, 3x the storage for 3, 4x for 4... And you'd also be limited by the slow upstream speed of most consumer broadband services.